# Not able to get state setter from context API, getting setGlobal is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with a React app. I need to keep an array of items in my global state.

This is my hook :

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import GlobalContext from "../context/GlobalProvider";

const useGlobal = () => {
return useContext(GlobalContext);
}

export default useGlobal;
```

And this is my provider :

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
const GlobalContext = createContext({});

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [global, setGlobal] = useState({});

return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ global, setGlobal }}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
)
}

export default GlobalContext;
```

In my App.js I have:

```
import useGlobal from "../hooks/useGlobal.js";
const { setGlobal } = useGlobal();

const handleGotoA = () => {
    
    const id_G = item
    const id_G1 = item1
    const id_G2 = item2
    setGlobal({ id_G, id_G1, id_G2 });
   
}
```

I get a this error:

```
"setGlobal is not a function"
```

And I can't find nor understand the reason why, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are calling this line `const { setGlobal } = useGlobal()` inside `App` function, not outside, as it's a hook, it should follow [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Something like:

```
const App = ()={
 //...
 const { setGlobal } = useGlobal(); // inside and at the top level of the component
 //...
}
```

Also, [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) is a reserved name in JavaScript. To avoid confusions and possible errors, use another name, like `globalData`. And finally make sure `App` is wrapped inside `GlobalProvider`, like this:

```
<GlobalProvider >
  <App/>
</GlobalProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

`useContext/useGlobal` are hooks, so you cannot use them outside of a `React component`.

Also, make sure your `hadleGoToA` component is inside the `GlobalContextProvider`:

```js
import useGlobal from "../hooks/useGlobal.js";

const HandleGotoA = () => { //Changed to uppercase to follow convention
    const { setGlobal } = useGlobal();

    const id_G = item
    const id_G1 = item1
    const id_G2 = item2
    setGlobal({ id_G, id_G1, id_G2 });
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with this line

```
const { setGlobal } = useGlobal();
```

I think it should be:

```
const { setGlobal } = useGlobal;
```

Because with the parenthesis, you are calling the function, therefore setGlobal is the result of the useGlobal function instead of the function itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First You can't use hooks outside components or custom hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

```
//custom hook
const useHandleGoToA = () => {
  // this line moved inside the hook 
  const { setGlobal } = useGlobal();

  const id_G = item
  const id_G1 = item1
  const id_G2 = item2
  setGlobal({ id_G, id_G1, id_G2 });

}

// component
const ComponentA = () => {
  // this line moved inside the component. 
  const { setGlobal } = useGlobal();

  const id_G = item
  const id_G1 = item1
  const id_G2 = item2
  setGlobal({ id_G, id_G1, id_G2 });

  return null;
}
```